# Set the default search to current folder?

Tags: macos, finder, search, defaults

The Finder's search bar is an integral part of my workflow. I am constantly using it to search the contents of files within various folders.

However, typing into this bar always searches the entire machine by default. In order to make it search just one folder, I have to click a second button.

Is there a way to change this so that it searches the current folder by default?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Finder -> Preferences -> Advanced**

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: @daviewales I can't believe the default is to search the whole computer.  I have literally never wanted to search that way.