# How can I view the root directory along with all its subdirectories in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos

I want to view the all (sub-)directories on my Mac partition in Finder. Both hidden and unhidden directories.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Navigate to `/` (e.g. use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.)
2. Then, in **list view** hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> while clicking the triangle. This will show all subdirectories of a certain folder.

By default, you'll don't see hidden files/directories. To show hidden files type the following commands in the `Terminal.app`:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

You can use the value `FALSE` in the `defaults write` command to unto this action.

[image]

Comment: How do I get to /? When I open new Finder Window I can only see Favourites which are the following directories: Dropbox, All My Files, AirDrop, Applications, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Movies, Music, Pictures

Comment: @Anonymous The root directory is partition where you installed OS X. By default is has the name `Macintosh HD`. I've added a picture.

Comment: I don't see Macintosh HD in Finder.

Comment: @Anonymous You can manually navigate to the `/` directory this way: 1) Open a finder window 2) hit CMD+Shift+G 3) enter `/`

Comment: OK, that good to know I'll use this keyboard shortcut. However, do you know why I can't seem to find Macintosh HD on Finder? Oh, and another thing, when I'm in a directory, let's say /Library, I want to search for a directory, but when I try to search it doesn't search from /Library but from "This Mac" instead. Is there a way to change its default mode?

Comment: @Anonymous **[Search current folder in Finder](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40016/13414)**

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure why you don't see the hard drive in Finder. Please check the *finder preferences* under *general* and *sidebar*. That should do it.

Comment: That was great, now I have my full hard-drive and the search is working properly. However, I still have two more questions: 1) how can I go back from the current directory to its parent directory if I'm using keyboard shortcut Command Shift G? 2)on / I only see Applications, Library, System, User Information and Users - why don't I see the real /?

Comment: I found how to go to the parent directory - enabling path bar, right click on the directory wanted enables that.

Comment: @Anonymous You don't see the "real" `/` because Finder only provides a graphical interface (GUI). Most users would get confused if your hard drive were simply named `/`. The `Terminal.app` on the other hand shows `/` when you're in the root directory.

Comment: neat I've managed to see the hidden files too now :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how I can use spotlight, for instance to write / and then it will open finder within / ? Instead of opening new Finder Window, then Command + Shift + G )

Answer (score 6):

Finder - Preferences.
Check the box to show your Mac there, and you will be able to easily navigate wherever you want.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. While it's never wrong to add a new answer to old questions, please provide a bit more details to distinct your answer from others.